# Building ArcGIS Model for identifying location?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I have a point shapefile of some plant species in an area of about 25000 sq.km. I have some other layers:

- unit boundary (private/public)
- roads
- research plots
- raster (land use)

If I overlay all the shapefiles and raster files, I will know the what kind of plant species is found in what land use, proximity of road to the plants, and unit type and so on.

For example, I have plant Species (A) in location 1 which has

- landtype: forest
- unit boundary: private
- research plot: control

Now I want to build a model that can identify other locations in the area with the same conditions as location 1.

Has anyone built such models in ModelBuilder, or have any idea what tools can be used to achieve this goal?

Comment: Asking for solutions in both QGIS and ArcGIS violates the "one question per question" rule. I edited your question to remove references to QGIS, since it seems like you're primarily interested in an ArcGIS solution. If you want a QGIS solution, please post a separate question.

Comment: Even after focussing your question on ArcGIS Desktop I think this remains too broad for focused Q&A.  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can either convert your vector data to raster, or reclassify the raster data such that for species A any land type forest equals 1 and all other land type values equal NoData.  Do the same for unit boundary and research plot.  After you have created these data add them together.  Anyplace with a value of 3 will be the areas that meet all your criteria. All other areas will have a NoData value.  Repeat this process for your other species types.  There are other issues you should look into like ensuring that your raster data have the same cell size and are registered together but all this can be managed in the geoprocessing environment settings.